# fill_parent doesn't work for RelativeLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout in a ScrollView on which I have set to fill_parent. However, it only fills horizontally, not vertically. There is more content I want to put in the RelativeLayout, but first I need to figure out why the RelativeLayout won't fill the height of the ScrollView.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:layout_below="@+id/previewButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/matchingWordsLabel"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Title:"
            />

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleLabel"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/titleLabel"
            android:ems="10" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add

```
android:fillViewPort="true"
```

to the `ScrollView`.

`fill_parent` or `match_parent` height inside a `ScrollView` doesn't really make sense and it is ignored - otherwise there would be no need for scrolling. `fillViewPort="true"` makes the scroll view take up all vertical space available on screen.

Answer (score -1):

Because the ScrollView can have only one child put a LinearLayout inside of it.  Inside the LinearLayout put the RelativeLayout.  Set the height to wrap_content.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/svRecord"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:visibility="visible" >
```